# NameError: name is not defined when using keyword=value

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it possible to pass a keyword=value as an argument to a function, where the value is an argument from another function?

For example

I define upper_dir

```
upper_dir='/somefolder'
```

I define my working dir:

```
def get_dir():

    repo_path = subprocess.call(["pwd"])
    return repo_path
```

I pass upper_dir to the create_branch function:

```
branch = gitmods.create_branch(hostname, upper_dir)
```

Now create_branch needs to call the syscmd function, passing it new_branch and upper_dir:

```
def create_branch(hostname, upper_dir):

    random = randint(100000, 999999)
    new_branch = 'git checkout -b removes-node-{0}'.format(random)
    syscmd(new_branch, upper_dir)

    repo_branch = 'git branch | grep "*"'
    branch = syscmd(repo_branch)
    branch = branch.split()[1]
    return branch
```

Several other functions call syscmd, but they only pass it 1 argument.
I'm trying to get 'cwd=' to default to the value contained by upper_dir

```
def syscmd(command, current_dir=upper_dir):

    current_dir=str(get_dir())
    popen = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=current_dir)
    out, err = popen.communicate()
    out = out.rstrip()
    return out
```

If the syscmd function didn't receive upper_dir, I want it to default to the value from get_dir (which is the current linux directory resulting from `pwd`

As far as I can tell, python can receive keyword=value arguments to a function, and default to a particular value when no argument is provided.
But what happens when your argument isn't a string, but instead an argument from another function?

I'm getting this error:

```
    def syscmd(command, current_dir=upper_dir):
NameError: name 'upper_dir' is not defined
```

Comment: `upper_dir` is not defined when the file is compiled.

Comment: How do I solve that when upper_dir is defined in __main__ but the functions it is being passed to are in a module?

Comment: As an aside, `os.getcwd()` also gets the current working directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual approach is to set the parameter's default to `None` and check it using an `if` statement:

```
def syscmd(command, current_dir=None):
    if current_dir is None:
        current_dir = str(get_dir())
    popen = subprocess.Popen(command, 
                             shell=True, 
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
                             cwd=current_dir)
    out, err = popen.communicate()
    out = out.rstrip()
    return out
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this more simply. `Popen` defaults to the current working directory if `cwd` is `None` and you can use the same rule.

```
def syscmd(command, cwd=None):
    popen = subprocess.Popen(command, 
                             shell=True, 
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
                             cwd=cwd)
    out, err = popen.communicate()
    out = out.rstrip()
    return out
```

If your command did path manipulations like `os.path.join`, you could use '.' as the default

```
def syscmd(command, cwd='.'):
    some_subpath = os.path.join(cwd, 'foo', 'bar')
    ...
```